# Как горизонтально центрировать заголовки в Latex

Tags: вёрстка, latex, tex

Оформляю документ в TeXstudio. Заголовки задаю с помощью команды \section, содержание формирую
с помощью \tableofcontents.
Подскажите, что необходимо прописать, что бы заголовки были по центру, а не по левому краю. Пробовала переопределить команду \renewcommand\section{\centering}, но в итоге весь текст съезжает.
И еще, список литературы вывожу с помощью \begin{thebibliography}, но в таком случае
он не отображается в содержании. Можно ли его как то вывести?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, это целых два отдельных вопроса. По первому: мне кажется, будет проще всего использовать пакет `titlesec`. В нем можно очень подробно указать, как должны формироваться названия отдельных секций. Список допустимых секций определяется классом документа. Я приведу пример для настройки только заголовка разделов `\section{}`, остальные можно оформить по аналогии.

Команда `\titleformat` имеет пять обязательных параметров. Думаю, по примеру ее использования будет понятно, что какой параметр означает. Но если кратко: первый - это переопределяемая команда (название секции), второй - задает формат заголовка (выравнивание, шрифт и все такое), третий - задает представление нумерации секции (метку), четвертый - задает отступ заголовка от номера секции (от метки), пятый параметр - может содержать код, который будет выполняться до тела заголовка (обычно не используется). В принципе, есть еще пара необязательных параметров, но о них лучше почитать в документации к пакету - они применяются в довольно экзотических случаях.

Что касается второго вопроса, то нужно просто добавить команду: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}` перед библиографией. Естественно, это пример для класса документа `article`. Если нужно использовать класс `book`, то слово `section` в команде нужно заменить на `chapter` (т.е. это определяется классом документа и тем, в какой секции нужно разместить в оглавлении библиографию). Пример использования также прилагаю.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename.\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}{\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.2em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph.}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph.}{1em}{}


\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Введение}
\section*{Введение}
\section[Короткое название первого раздела для оглавления]{Очень длинная строка в названии раздела должна быть записана с переносом на новую строку}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Короткая строка в названии раздела}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{Еще одна короткая строка в названии раздела}
\lipsum[3-4]

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{accelconf-ref}
    C. Petit-Jean-Genaz and J. Poole, ``JACoW, A service to the Accelerator Community,''
    EPAC'04, Lucerne, July 2004, THZCH03,  p.~249, \texttt{http://www.JACoW.org}
    
    \bibitem{jacow-help} A. Name and D. Person, Phys. Rev. Lett. 25 (1997) 56.
    
    \bibitem{exampl-ref}
    A.N. Other, ``A Very Interesting Paper,'' EPAC'96, Sitges, June 1996, MOPCH31, p. 7984 (1996),
    \texttt{http://www.JACoW.org}  \{no period after URL\}
    
    \bibitem{exampl-ref2}
    F.E.~Black et al., {\it This is a Very Interesting Book}, (New York: Knopf, 2007), 52.
    
    \bibitem{exampl-ref3}
    G.B.~Smith et al., ``Title of Paper,'' MOXAP07, these proceedings.
\end{thebibliography}

\tableofcontents    
\end{document}
```

*Пример получившегося заголовка:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разобралась, спасибо большое. А подскажите еще пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, что бы у первого заголовка нумерации тоже не было? Вот сейчас список литературы отображается в содержание без нумерации, можно ли так с введением?

Comment: @Лидия, да, можно конечно. Нужно написать команду заголовка со звездочкой, но тогда это название не попадет в оглавление. И второй шаг - как и с библиографией перед разделом нужно добавить команду `\addcontentsline`:
`\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Введение}
    \section*{Введение}`. PS: добавил эти строчки и в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось, пойду дальше изучать.